# Loading the different UINavigationController in iOS: Navigation flow not working

Tags: ios

I am working on the Universal application, I would like to load the different files for iPad and iPhone.

The navigation flow is not working . Any help appreciated.

I am writing the code like as below in app delegate,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"  bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController;

UINavigationController *navViewController;




if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
    navViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"];
} else {
    navViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
}

// self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
self.window.rootViewController = navViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

[image]

Comment: how can you use same identifier ViewController_iPad for navigationVC and viewController

Comment: now I changed but not working

Comment: so your topViewController is visible? or are you getting black screen?

Comment: Top view controller is visible, Actually my storyboard contains two UINavigationControllers, If I set the iPad navigation controller as InitialViewController then navigation flow is working but for iPhone is not working vice versa.

Comment: did you check "ViewController" is navigation controller ?

Comment: Actually its a UIViewController. I embedded it in the UINavigationcontroller

Comment: so when you trying to navigate, Is it being crashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey bro try this once,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;

if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
    [navigationController pushViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"] animated:NO];
} else {
    [navigationController pushViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"] animated:NO];
}

self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

are you added like this, for example

> in here you get the identifier of UINavigation controller not UIViewcontroller, so try like

```
if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
navViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"];
} else {
navViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"XXXX"];
}
```

[image]

**Updated**

**Choice-1**

you can directly access as per your way just modify this no need of `UINavigationController *navViewController;` here

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"  bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController;

if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
    viewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"];
} else {
    viewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
}

  self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
// self.window.rootViewController = navViewController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
```

**Choice-2**

remove the storyboard on your storyboard screen and create the navigation controller on progrmatically , like

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"  bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController;

if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
    viewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"];
} else {
    viewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
}

    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
//  self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
 self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
```

Comment: Yes, am doing same as above

Comment: @SaiBharathYadav -- just wait I upadte answer in 3 ways

Comment: I have used the below code,

if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
    [navigationController pushViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"] animated:NO];
} else {
    [navigationController pushViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"] animated:NO];
}

Answer (score 1):

set identifier of UINavigation controller in storyboard instead of UIViewController Identifier because you are loading navigation controller from story board not viewcontroller.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"  bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController;

    UINavigationController *navViewController;

    if (IDIOM == IPAD)
    {
        navViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"];
    }
else
    {
        navViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    }

self.window.rootViewController = navViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: no saood , if you create the navigation controller progrmatically, it will added another one stack on navigation stack, check the update question once and update your answer please

Comment: ok anbu, as you added screen shot, i updated my answer. check it

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik read comments in my post. this will solve your problem

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik if your problem has solved then don't forget to rate :)

Comment: question I am not asked bro, sry

Answer (score 1):

I think My code will help you

add this line in `appdelegate.h`

```
@property (strong , nonatomic)UINavigationController *mainNavController;
```

add this line in `appdelegate.m` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


    if (IDIOM == IPAD)
    {
         self.window.rootViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_iPad"];
    }
else
    {
         self.window.rootViewController  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    }
    self.mainNavController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```